# How can I install Chaotica on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

I've already tried using commands that were provided by someone here as someone else asked about this software before but they did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Download](https://www.chaoticafractals.com/dist/chaotica_x64_v2.2.2.tar.gz) the archive and move it to `/opt/` by doing

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo cp chaotica_x64_v2.2.2.tar.gz /opt/
cd /opt/
sudo tar xvfz chaotica_x64_v2.2.2.tar.gz
```

It will create  directory `/opt/chaotica_x64_v2.2.2/` so do (future versions might have a higher version so press tab after `/opt/cha`):

```
cd /opt/chaotica_x64_v2.2.2/
```

and

```
./chaotica
```

That is it.

---

[System requirements:](https://www.chaoticafractals.com/manual/getting_started/system_requirements)

- CPU with SSE4
- 4GB of RAM
- 100MB of hard drive space

Recommended:

- 16 GB+ of RAM for very high resolution images (e.g. when rendering for print)
- GPU: Discrete GPU with 8 GB + of RAM, for example Nvidia GTX 1070 + or AMD Radeon RX 5700 +

Proof it works:

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions but got this at the end: ./chaotica: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by ./chaotica)
./chaotica: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./chaotica)
./chaotica: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /opt/chaotica_x64_v2.2.2/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
./chaotica: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /opt/chaotica_x64_v2.2.2/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)   Does that mean I need to download the required things?

Comment: Not going to be possible. You are not using  Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: No, mine is 16.04

Comment: Please upgrade to a supported release. 16.04 went end of life on April 30th 2021 so it is no longer possible to install software on it. Instructions on AU are always for current releases.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.